# Data not downloaded after clearing BaseTable and Tracking table

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using Sync Framework 2.1 and Sql Server 2014 in Server & Client.
Data is downloaded from Server to Client.(SyncDirectionOrder.Download)
I have cleared the data in Base table and the tracking table in Client database. Once I started the sync, No data was downloaded to Client.
My concern is to download data from Server after clearing table.
How to accomplish this? Highly appreciated your help.

Comment: Simply saying, I want to Clear 1 table in Client DB and Re-Download data from server. anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

you have cleared the base and tracking table, but the information of what was previously synched is stored in the sync knowledge in the scope_info table. the metadata on what needs to be synched is to compare metadata to what has changed in the source vs the the metadata in the target database. if nothing has changed in the source, even if your table is emptied, the sync knowledge will simply think it already had those rows from prior syncs.

Comment: thanks Junet. So how do I update metadata manually, in order to re-download?